# Devise create user and login on test setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, authentication, devise

**app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

    # GET /categories
    # GET /categories.json
    def index
        @categories = Category.all
    end

    # GET /categories/1
    # GET /categories/1.json
    def show
        if session[:cart] then
            @cart = session[:cart]
        else
            @cart = {}
        end
    end

    # GET /categories/new
    def new
        if current_user.admin?
            @category = Category.new
        end
    end

    # GET /categories/1/edit
    def edit
        if current_user.admin?
        end
    end

    # POST /categories
    # POST /categories.json
    def create
        if current_user.admin?
            @category = Category.new(category_params)

            respond_to do |format|
                if @category.save
                    format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
                    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
                else
                    format.html { render :new }
                    format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                end
            end
        end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /categories/1
    # PATCH/PUT /categories/1.json
    def update
        if current_user.admin?
            respond_to do |format|
                if @category.update(category_params)
                    format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
                    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
                else
                    format.html { render :edit }
                    format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                end
            end
        end
    end

    # DELETE /categories/1
    # DELETE /categories/1.json
    def destroy
        if current_user.admin?
            @category.destroy
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
                format.json { head :no_content }
            end
        end
    end

    private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_category
            @category = Category.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def category_params
            params.require(:category).permit(:name, :desc)
        end
end
```

In the controller above I'm preventing standard users to create, update or destroy categories by checking `if current_user.admin?`. But it's causing some problems in the tests.

**test/controllers/categories_controller.rb:**

```
require 'test_helper'

class CategoriesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @category = categories(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:categories)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create category" do
    assert_difference('Category.count') do
      post :create, category: { desc: @category.desc, name: @category.name }
    end

    assert_redirected_to category_path(assigns(:category))
  end

  test "should show category" do
    get :show, id: @category
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @category
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update category" do
    patch :update, id: @category, category: { desc: @category.desc, name: @category.name }
    assert_redirected_to category_path(assigns(:category))
  end

  test "should destroy category" do
    assert_difference('Category.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @category
    end

    assert_redirected_to categories_path
  end
end
```

Because of the restriction, tests related with create, update or destroy are failing. I think I need to create an admin user and login on test setup. But I don't know how to do this.

I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for users part of the app.

I'm running my tests with `rake test:functionals`. How can I simulate user create and login in my tests?

If you want to look to the whole project: https://github.com/mertyildiran/SCOR

Comment: Are you using something to fake entities, like factory_girl or something?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida No I'm not using factory_girl gem.

Comment: Then an option would be seeding your test database with at least to users, and admin and a common user, and use them in your tests.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida with `load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"` yes. Then what should I do for simulate login in my tests?

Comment: This may be a bit harsh, but you may always do the process of logging in, passing the correct parameters in your tests to get an authentication token.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida please explain in the answers in detail. I need help about this please. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fixtures to create an admin user in the test database (you probably already have a `test/fixtures/users.yml` file), and Devise's [Test helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers) to sign in:

```
sign_in :user, users(:admin)
```

If your users are confirmable, remember to set a `confirmed_at` date.

Check out the [Devise wiki article on testing Rails controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29).

Comment: Yeah I realized my `test/fixtures/users.yml` was not correct so I corrected and your answer is worked.